# Firefox blurs when changing the input type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I have this snippet which changes an input type from text to number on the focus event, and back to text on the blur event.

It seems that in Firefox, changing the type triggers a blur, which means you can never get focus.

Is this a known bug and is there a workaround?

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  //.controller('MainController', MainController)
  .directive("test", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        element.bind("blur", function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            element.attr("type", "text");

          });
        });

        element.bind("focus", function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            element.attr("type", "number");

          });
        });
      }
    };
  });


function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = 90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" test ng-model="test" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is some issue with Angular. I tried pure JS and it's working - check it out here - https://jsbin.com/fovosojutu/edit?html,output

Comment: @metal03326 seems to be right, setting `element[0].type = "number";` does work too, but an unreadable error is thrown. (I don't know nothing about angular)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried element[0].focus() and I saw the same unreadable error :/

Comment: @metal03326 but what if you add the blur function, like so: https://jsbin.com/duxunerapi/edit?html,output

Comment: I have the same issue. Did yuo found a workaround?

Comment: Also happens in **[jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/BobStein/4mL902vo/7/)**. Changing an input type attribute from text to number causes a blur. Bug has been [languishing in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=981248) more than 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found this workaround:
In focus() event just disable the blur event before changing input type and re-enable after changing.

My code snipplet (Angular 4):

```
@HostListener("focus", ["$event"])
onFocus($event) {
    const onBlur = this.onBlur;
    this.onBlur = (e) => {};
    ...
    $event.target.type = "number";
    this.onBlur = onBlur;
}

@HostListener("blur", ["$event"])
onBlur($event) {
    $event.target.type = "text";
}
```

Hope it helps ;-)